# Spring Cloud Config Vault Strange Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-vault

We are using Spring Cloud 2.2.6.RELEASE using vault for storage for our microservices and our Vault team has complained about number of request, they provided Splunk log access and I see many request with the following:

```
{ [-]
auth: { [+]
policies: [ [+]
]
token_issue_time: 2020-10-16T16:28:12-05:00
token_policies: [ [+]
]
token_ttl: 34164000
token_type: service
}
request: { [-]
client_token: hmac-sha256:48482518080211c5392d4a28f00838a8e83c404a7b5587eeb19e7d0dc73f8206
client_token_accessor: hmac-sha256:c33c41206e025bfd02eb4b4293b9cdec29d4cfda3a5118f4dea28754888ce502
id: 96676538-fe03-1eaa-d25d-f0bd942072fc
mount_type: kv
namespace: { [+]
}
operation: read
path: secret/data/app
remote_address: 156.36.248.6
}
time: 2021-04-23T17:59:55.815091744Z
type: request
}
```

I do see the normal request for secret/data/application, etc, but why would there be a request for ***secret/data/app***?

Any ideas on how or where this could be made?

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Cloud Vault adds the data/ context between the mount path and
> the actual context path.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/multi/multi_vault.config.backends.html